# Figure instead of InteractiveDynamics app for julia agents model

Tags: julia, makie.jl, agents.jl

I am following the schelling.jl tutorial from the Agents.jl package (https://juliadynamics.github.io/Agents.jl/stable/examples/schelling/). Towards the end of the tutorial they create an interactive application. But when I run the script (`include("schelling.jl")`), I end up with figure instead of an interactive app (cannot click on the run, reset buttons since it appears to be a figure). Any ideas how I get it as an interactive app?

```
using InteractiveDynamics
figure, adf, mdf = abm_data_exploration(model, agent_step!, dummystep, parange; ac=groupcolor, am=groupmarker, as = 10, adata, alabels)
```

Note I am using vscode IDE

[image]

Comment: Which backend are you using ? (CairoMakie?)

Comment: Yep I am using CairoMakie

Comment: That's what I thought.. see the answer below ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the proper plotting backend, CairoMakie can output static vector graphics but it can't open interactive windows. You can use GLMakie or WGLMakie instead.

| Package | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [GLMakie.jl](https://github.com/MakieOrg/Makie.jl/blob/master/docs/documentation/backends/glmakie.md) | GPU-powered, interactive 2D and 3D plotting in standalone GLFW.jl windows. |
| [CairoMakie.jl](https://github.com/MakieOrg/Makie.jl/blob/master/docs/documentation/backends/cairomakie.md) | Cairo.jl based, non-interactive 2D backend for publication-quality vector graphics. |
| [WGLMakie.jl](https://github.com/MakieOrg/Makie.jl/blob/master/docs/documentation/backends/wglmakie.md) | WebGL-based interactive 2D and 3D plotting that runs within browsers. |
| [RPRMakie.jl](https://github.com/MakieOrg/Makie.jl/blob/master/docs/documentation/backends/rprmakie.md) | An experimental ray tracing backend. |

@see [Mackie's Backends & Output](https://github.com/MakieOrg/Makie.jl/blob/master/docs/documentation/backends.md)